# How do I write a generic TFS query to show the Assigned items for the current users "Direct Reports"

Tags: tfs, active-directory

TFS Query Editor allows the user to specify that the "Assigned To" field use the "=" operator against "@Me" to show all the item assigned to the current user.

Is there a way for TFS to query all the items assigned to current user's "Direct Reports" as controlled by AD so that when AD is updated, the query reflects that?

Comment: Sounds like a great idea for an app, as I am not aware of any built in functionality for this. There is plenty of code out there for the API queries. Marry that up with a tree view, and an iteration through AD, and you would be good to go. Also a great suggestion for Microsoft.

Answer (score 1):

You need to achieve it via using TFS API.

Firstly, you need to get the current user via code.

```
TfsTeamProjectCollection tfctc = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("http://tfsservername:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection"));

        var uniquename= tfctc.AuthorizedIdentity.UniqueName;
```

Secondly, get the direct report for that user in AD. Please check callykalpana's reply in this link for the details how to do it: http://forums.asp.net/t/1901288.aspx?get+direct+reports+of+a+logged+user+from+active+directory+into+a+dropdown+list

Finally, get work items for that director report user via using TFS API.

```
TfsTeamProjectCollection tfctc = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("http://tfsservername:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection"));
        WorkItemStore wis = tfctc.GetService<WorkItemStore>();
        List<int> wiToDelete = new List<int>();
        string wiql = "SELECT * FROM WorkItems WHERE [System.AssignedTo] ='Direct Report'";
```